# What is the difference between initializing hash two times and clear?

Tags: ruby, hash

Suppose I have an `hash = {1=>1,2=>2}` to clear the values I can do either `hash = {}` or `hash.clear` . What is the difference between them?

Comment: check here for info http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html

Comment: @LHH, I did. I just could not understand why I would use #clear if I can initialize new hash to clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-clear), if you see the source code for `clear` method, it iterates through each element in the hash and removes it.

When you do `hash = {}`, it will just create a new empty hash object but the old object will still be in memory ready for garbage collection if there are no other references for that object.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different.

The first one will simply bind the local variable `hash` to a different object. In particular, it will *not* "clear the values", as you claim:

```
hash = {i: 'am', still: 'there'}
another = hash

hash = {}

another
# => {i: 'am', still: 'there'}
```

The second one *will* actually clear the values:

```
hash = {i: 'am', still: 'there'}
another = hash

hash.clear

another
# => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Atri's answer is right, but beyond the Hash still existing in memory for GC when you use reassignment -- is if the array is still actually referenced by another variable.

A Hash is an object, a variable is just a pointer or reference to it. #clear clears the object itself, reassigning the variable just points the variable to a new Hash.

```
hash1 = {1=>1,2=>2}
hash2 = hash1
puts hash1 # => {1=>1,2=>2}
puts hash2 # => {1=>1,2=>2}
hash1 = {}
puts hash1 # => {}
puts hash2 # => {1=>1,2=>2}

hash1 = {1=>1,2=>2}
hash2 = hash1 
hash1.clear
puts hash1 # => {}
puts hash2 # => {}
```